# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, attributeerror, tensor

I downloaded this code from GitHub.

```
predicted_id = tf.multinomial(tf.exp(predictions), num_samples=1)[0][0].numpy()
```

But I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I suspect the place where you copied the code from had [eager execution enabled](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/eager/README.md), i.e. had invoked [`tf.enable_eager_execution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/enable_eager_execution) at the start of the program.

You could do the same.

UPDATE: Note that eager execution is enabled by default in TensorFlow 2.0. So the answer above applies only to TensorFlow 1.x

Comment: It changes the TensirFlie APIs so that they execute operations on tensors immediately (as opposed to adding the operations to a graph). See the links in the answer above for details

Answer (score 103):

Since the accepted answer did not solve the problem for me so I thought it might be helpful for some people who face the problem and that already have tensorflow version >= 2.2.0 and eager execution enabled.

The issue seems to be that for certain functions during the fitting `model.fit()`
the `@tf.function` decorator prohibits the execution of functions like `tensor.numpy()` for performance reasons.

The solution for me was to pass the flag [`run_eagerly=True`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager?hl=en) to the `model.compile()` like this:

```
model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)
```

Answer (score 33):

Tensorflow 2 has a config option to run functions "eagerly" which will enable getting Tensor values via `.numpy()` method. To enable eager execution, use following command:

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

Note that this is useful mainly for debugging.

See also: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly

Comment: For the record, this answer is the only thing that gave me a change in error output. I'm getting this error, but I'm on TF 2.0, not 1.x, so I think that's why most other answers are not helpful for me.

Answer (score 24):

This can also happen in TF2.0 if your code is wrapped in a @tf.function or inside a Keras layer. Both of those run in graph mode. There's a lot of secretly broken code out of there because behavior differs between eager and graph modes and people are not aware that they're switching contexts, so be careful!

Comment: @Stark see Alexander's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596006/9095840 or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057458/9095840

Answer (score 10):

It happens in older version of TF. So try `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

otherwise run

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

If you are using Jupyter notebook, restart the Kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tf.get_static_value()` to obtain the value of a tensor. This has the benefit of not needing eager mode. See docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_static_value).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33120772)

Answer (score 1):

`tf.multinomial` returns a Tensor object that contains a 2D list with drawn samples of shape `[batch_size, num_samples]`. Calling `.eval()` on that tensor object is expected to return a numpy ndarray.

Something like this:

```
predicted_id = tf.multinomial(tf.exp(predictions), num_samples=1)[0][0].eval()
```

You also need to ensure that you have a session active (doesn't make a lot of sense otherwise):

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    predicted_id = tf.multinomial(tf.exp(predictions), num_samples=1)[0][0].eval()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a tf.function(): But what has worked for me is to transform the numpy array into a tensorflow tensor via  `tf.convert_to_tensor` [Doku](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) and then go ahead with tensorflow. Maybe this trick could be useful for anyone...

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar error when I run code something like the following,

```
tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)
tensor.numpy()  # throw AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I use anaconda 3 with tensorflow 1.14.0. I upgraded tensorflow with the command below

```
conda update tensorflow
```

now tensorflow is 2.0.0, issue fixed. Try this to see if it resolves your issue.