# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy' when using custom metrics function

Tags: tensorflow

I want to count the number of matching label in a custom error function

I tested :

```
def custom__error(y_true, y_pred):
  # ---- y_pred
  yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred)
  bp = tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  cp = tf.keras.backend.eval(bp)
  # ---- y_true
  yt = tf.nn.softmax( y_true )
  bt = tf.argsort(yt,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  ct = tf.keras.backend.eval(bt)
  # ---- common
  count =  tf.sets.intersection(cp[None,:10],ct[None,:10])
  return count
```

but I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'
```

I also tried :

```
 def custom__error(y_true, y_pred):
  # ---- y_pred
  yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred)
  bp = tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  cp = bp.to_numpy()
  xcp = cp[None,:10]
  # ---- y_true
  yt = tf.nn.softmax( y_true )
  bt = tf.argsort(yt,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  ct = bt.to_numpy()
  xct = ct[None,:10]
  # ---- common
  count =  tf.sets.intersection(tf.convert_to_tensor(xcp),tf.convert_to_tensor(xct))
  return count
```

I don't know how to use **tf.sets.intersection** inside tensorflow **backend** function.

Can someone help me understand ?

---

The complete error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-319-eed924909205> in <module>()
      4 print(optimizer.learning_rate.numpy())  # or print(optimizer.lr.numpy())
      5 model_loss=custom__loss(100,100,1,0.01)
----> 6 model.compile(loss=model_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy',custom__error])

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   3798     return nest.pack_sequence_as(
   3799         self._outputs_structure,
-> 3800         [x._numpy() for x in outputs],  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3801         expand_composites=True)
   3802 

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy'
```

---

I tried to return numpy array :

```
return count.to_numpy()
```

or with:

```
def custom__error(y_true, y_pred):
  # ---- y_pred
  yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred)
  bp = tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  cp = bp.to_numpy()
  xcp = cp[None,:10]
  # ---- y_true
  yt = tf.nn.softmax( y_true )
  bt = tf.argsort(yt,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
  ct = bt.to_numpy()
  xct = ct[None,:10]
  # ---- common
  count =  tf.sets.intersection(xcp,xct)
  return count
```

but got the same error:

```
<ipython-input-114-59d27aab97e1> in custom__error(y_true, y_pred)
      3   yp = tf.nn.softmax( y_pred)
      4   bp = tf.argsort(yp,axis=-1,direction='DESCENDING',stable=False,name=None)
----> 5   cp = bp.to_numpy()
      6   xcp = cp[None,:10]
      7   # ---- y_true

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

---

```
<ipython-input-91-16ca4acce397> in custom__error(y_true, y_pred)
     12   # ---- common
     13   count =  tf.sets.intersection(xcp,xct)
---> 14   return count.numpy()
     15 
     16 

AttributeError: 'SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Please share the complete error message

Comment: @Kashinath Patekar  Complete error message added

Comment: The title should be something like "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_numpy' when using custom metrics function". That will help other users to find this question. I am proposing an edit.

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```py
model.compile(loss=model_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy',custom__error])
```

the `custom__error` function is expected to return a numpy array, whereas `tf.insersection` would give you `Tensor`'s in this case because `y_true` and `y_pred` passed to `tf.intersection` are `tensor`s themselves.

Hence you would first need to convert `count` to a numpy array before returning it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554855/11389917) answer might help.

**Edit:**
`count` is `SparseTensor`, hence first convert it to a dense tensor with:

```py
dcount = tf.sparse.to_dense(count)
```

Then you need to check the mode in which tensorflow is running.
You can it using this:

```py
tf.executing_eagerly()
```

- If this returns `True`:
  Eager mode active. You need to call `.numpy()` on the tensor to be converted.
- If this returns `False`:
  Graph mode active. You need to call `.eval()` on the tensor to be converted.

If you like you can automate it for you:

```py
if tf.executing_eagerly():
    return dcount.numpy()
else
    return dcount.eval()
```

Credit: [TF 2.0 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' while using .numpy() although eager execution enabled by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519)

If you are using Tensorflow 1.x, you may need to enable eager execution manually. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359348/11389917) answer for details.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The method .to_numpy() does not exist, hence the error. The error *did* change. It was as different place, and for different reason. I hope the updated answer solves the issue for you, cheers!

Comment: <ipython-input-91-16ca4acce397> in custom__error(y_true, y_pred)
     12   # ---- common
     13   count =  tf.sets.intersection(xcp,xct)
---> 14   return count.numpy()
     15 
     16 

AttributeError: 'SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Thanks for your help : TensorFlow 2.x selected,but got SparseTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'.

Comment: Then you would first need to convert the sparse tensor to dense tensor. (SparseTensor -> Tensor). A quick Google search should do the trick. To recap, original `count` (SparseTensor) => (dense) Tensor => numpy array

Comment: count =  tf.sets.intersection(xcp,xct)
  dcount = tf.sparse.to_dense(count)
  return dcount.numpy()

Comment: <ipython-input-54-617cc234ea96> in custom__error(y_true, y_pred)
     13   count =  tf.sets.intersection(xcp,xct)
     14   dcount = tf.sparse.to_dense(count)
---> 15   return dcount.numpy()
     16 
     17 

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Could you give a link to the colab notebook, if it is one? this seems unusual

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14TC0Hgf_aKtSTwlZvUKMlVYZUdvUuVJv?usp=sharing