# Tensorflow Object to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a custom F1 score function in Keras but my target variable is an array and I don't want to one hot encode them, so I am using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as a loss.

```
from keras import backend as K
def f1(y_true, y_pred):
  print(type(y_true))
  return y_true
```

When I run the above code I am getting y_true and y_pred as `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`. How can we convert y_true and y_pred to NumPy array, so that I can implement sklearn's F1 score function upon them?

Comment: `y_true.numpy()` should give you a numpy array

Comment: does the above work for you?

Comment: I am getting this following error. ```AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'```

Comment: What version of TF are you using?

Comment: I'm not a TF user, but I think only eager tensors have this attribute.

Comment: There are lots of SO questions with this error in the title, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy

Answer (score 0):

Use (as also suggested by @learner in comments):

```
y_true = y_true.numpy()
y_pred = y_pred.numpy()
```