# How to use the tensors inside a Keras custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, loss-function

I need to train a model with a custom loss function, which shall also update some external function right after the prediction, like this:

```py
def loss_fct(y_true, y_pred):
    global feeder
 
    # Change values of feeder given y_pred
    for value in y_pred:
        feeder.do_something(value)
    
    return K.mean(y_true - y_pred, axis=-1)
```

However this doesn't work, as TF cannot iterate through tensors in AutoGraph:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

---

My model looks like this

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(DIM, )))
model.add(Dense(DIM, activation=None))
model.add(Dense(16, activation=None))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fct)
model.summary()
```

And it is trained like this:

```py
model.fit(x=feeder.feed,
    epochs=18,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=None,
)
```

Where `feeder.feed` is a generator yielding 2 NumPy arrays.

---

Comment: First, check which values your generator yields. `y_pred` seems to be a 4 dim tensor. So, what do you expect with iteration over it to happen? You can iterate indirectly, like something `y_true[0]` etc by using the tensor's shape also

Comment: Yes you are right. ```y_pred``` can be for example ```[1, 0, 1, 0]```. However I cannot do ```y_true[0]``` while the program is running inside Autograph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I have came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596006/9917230). It seems that nothing is wrong with the approach, but it's rather a `Tensorflow >= 2.2.0` bug, where [Eager Execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is enabled by default.

Finally, to solve this problem use `model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)` and iteration and access to tensors during training will be available.