# Why deosn't .numpy() work for Tensor object in python?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to a custom loss function for tensorflow. Because I was trying to see what was going on in the loss function, I tried to print the input of the loss function as a numpy array using `.numpy()`, but I got an error. My code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def windowDataset(df, split=0.2, shuffleBuffer=7, batchSize=10):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df).window(5, 1, drop_remainder=True)# sequence {{},...,{}}
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(5)) # {[], ..., []}
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: (x[:-1], x[-1])) # {[(,)],..., [(,)]}
    split = round((1-split)*len(list(dataset)))
    train = dataset.take(split).shuffle(shuffleBuffer).batch(batchSize)
    val = dataset.skip(split)
    return train, val

def customLoss(yTrue, yPredict):
    print(yTrue)
    print(yTrue.numpy())
    return 0

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
])
model.compile(loss=customLoss, optimizer='Adam')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 4))
train, val = windowDataset(df)
model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=10)
```

This will print out:

```
Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)
```

but then there will be a error message:

```
...AttributeError: in user code:

    C:\Users\119433\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-22-f015b3791cf2>:16 customLoss  *
        print(yTrue.numpy())

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Now if I try something like this:

```
test = tf.constant([1,2,3])
print(test)
print(test.numpy())
```

everything works fine and I get this return:

```
tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
[1 2 3]
```

So Tensor does has .numpy() method. So why didn't it work for the custom loss function?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy) link.

Comment: Yeah the link is useful. Adding `run_eagerly=True` in model.compile() solved my problem. Thanks!