# How to check if tensor is symbolic?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to add an additional loss with `add_loss` to a hidden layer in my model, and have added it in the `call()` function for that layer. I want to convert the input to a numpy array, but when I call `input.numpy()`, it fails with the error:

> 'AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy''.

I've checked and it doesn't raise this error with other tensors. So there must be symbolic tensors being passed into the `call()` function as input.

How could I check if the input a symbolic tensor or not?

Here's the layer which I was referring to calling `inputs.numpy()` raises the error.

```
class Encoder(layers.Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        self.filters=filters
        self.kernel_size=kernel_size
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(filters, kernel_size, **kwargs)
    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs.numpy())
        return super(Encoder, self).call(inputs)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example to reproduce the error.

Comment: Provided, let me know if you need more!

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy

Comment: `inputs` will be a Symbolic Tensor. To perform operations on it, use the methods provided in `tf.keras.backend` module.