# How can I change a tensor to NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to exchange `Tensor` `a` to a NumPy two-dimensional array for getting a heat map.

> (Tensor(1, 64, 64, 1) -> numpy (64, 64))

I tried `x.numpy()`, but it doesn't work. The error message is this:

> AttributeError: in user code: :187 call  * x_np=x.numpy() /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:401 **getattr** self.**getattribute**(name) AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

This is the tensor information and type of the tensor:

```
Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(1, 64, 64, 1), dtype=float32)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

and I don't know what `ExpandDims:0` means (what is this argv?).

```
Tensorflow:2.6.0
Numpy:1.21.2
```

I made the test code that has the same Tensor type, shape, and env, and it works.

What should I do?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
print(tf.__version__)
print(numpy.__version__)

a = tf.constant([[[[0.1]*1]*64]*64])
print(a)
print(a.numpy())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy)

Comment: Did you try updating/ reinstalling latest `tensorflow`?

Comment: @Teshan Shanuka J  yes but it didnt work... I run in Colab so you don't have to worry about library obsolescence

Comment: @ashraful16 i tried all of those solutons.. but it does not work and get the same error. `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: can you send code? how create tensor array?

Comment: send here line that create tensor i can help you

Comment: @user1740577 this is the RepNet tutorial code and I want to  get self-similarity matrix.  The link is https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/google-research/blob/master/repnet/repnet_colab.ipynb#scrollTo=Y0iMnWR_nk9E. In SetUp's first block, i want to get  numpy array of this x.  `x = get_sims(x, self.temperature) `

Comment: why are you send all code? I say give me example like this : (Tensor(1,64,64,1)) then I can change this to `numpy(64,64)`

Comment: @user1740577 hmm I made the test code that has the same Tensor type,shape, and env. and it works..... idk what to do.. can you advise?

Comment: now you learn never to run all code and first split code to small pieces. have good time. do you have any question?

Comment: I solved!! It wwas the problem of declaration. I declared twice like 'import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf \n import tensorflow as tf ' They conflicted and i solved by changing  ` import tensorflow as tf` to  `import tensorflow as originTF` !!

Comment: please send your answer to your own question. then the future users can learn from you :))