# Printing a TensorFlow object without using session

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am receiving different errors when trying to print a TensorFlow object.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
```

The versions of both TensorFlow and numpy are 2.6 and 1.19.5, respectively.

```
print("np version:", np.__version__)
print("tf version:" ,tf.version.VERSION)
print("eager is on? ", tf.executing_eagerly())

#np version: 1.19.5
#tf version: 2.6.0
#eager is on?  True
```

Now, let me create a small array and turn it into a `tf` object.

```
arr= [0,1.2,-0.8]
arr = tf.constant(arr, dtype = tf.float32)
```

When I use `tf.print` or `tf.compat.v1.print(arr)`, nothing happens. When I call `numpy`, I do receive an error.

```
tf.compat.v1.print(arr.numpy())

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

The only thing that has worked so far is ;

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:  print(arr.eval()) 

#[ 0.   1.2 -0.8]
```

However, I would like to use `numpy` since my goal is to print certain features of the network during the traning phase. For instance, if I want to print the learning rate, I call  `with  tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:  print(model.optimizer.learning_rate.eval())` . Yet, it returns me another error.

```
 'ExponentialDecay' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

I was able to use `numpy` to print everything before, however, I updated both `TensorFlow` and `numpy` packages and now am facing so many incompatibilities. The worst thing is that I don't remember which versions I was using.

I followed every step explainedd in this post
[AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy). It did not help me.

Comment: don't use NumPy functions in a Tensorflow model/training script

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any specific reason why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code gives me an output -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print("np version:", np.__version__)
print("tf version:" ,tf.version.VERSION)
print("eager is on? ", tf.executing_eagerly())
tf.enable_eager_execution()

arr= [0,1.2,-0.8]
arr = tf.constant(arr, dtype = tf.float32)

tf.compat.v1.print(arr.numpy())
```

Output: `array([ 0. ,  1.2, -0.8], dtype=float32)`

Did you add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was on, but I restarted the kernel and now even ````tf.print```` works fine.

Comment: However, what I intend to do is still not working. when I call ````tf.compat.v1.print(model.optimizer.learning_rate)```` , it prints````keras.optimizer_v2.learning_rate_schedule.ExponentialDecay object at 0x0000021BDCC520D0>````

Comment: sorry I missed that part, can you please provide how you are creating the model? Maybe the complete code block until you hit the error.

Comment: No worries! Here's the solution I found:  ````lr = model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32),
            print(lr)````