# Extract the value of a Tensorflow/Keras GradientTape gradient of a variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gradienttape

**In short**: I have a custom loss layer in Tensorflow/Keras 2+, which implements a loss function involving two variables, which also go through minimization. And it works, as can be seen below. I wish to track the loss gradients with respect to these two variables. Using `GradientTape.gradient()` seems to work judging from `tf.print()` output. But I have no idea how to keep the actual values.

**In detail**:

Suppose this is my custom loss layer (yes, the loss function is silly, everything is over-simplified for reproducibility):

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, Callback
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class MyLoss(Layer):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        super(MyLoss, self).__init__()
        self.var1 = K.variable(var1) # or tf.Variable(var1) etc.
        self.var2 = K.variable(var2)
    
    def get_vars(self):
        return self.var1, self.var2
    
    def get_gradients(self):
        return self.grads

    def custom_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        loss = self.var1 * K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred)) + self.var2 ** 2
        return loss

    def compute_gradients(self, y_true, y_pred):
        with tf.GradientTape() as g:
          loss = self.custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)
          return loss, g.gradient(loss, [self.var1, self.var2])
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        loss, grads = self.compute_gradients(y_true, y_pred)
        self.grads = grads
        # tf.print(grads)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return y_pred
```

Suppose these are my data and `Model` (yes, `y` enters the model as an additional input, this works and isn't related):

```py
n_col = 10
n_row = 1000
X = np.random.normal(size=(n_row, n_col))
beta = np.arange(10)
y = X @ beta

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
y_input = Input(shape=(1,))
hidden1 = Dense(10)(inputs)
output = Dense(1)(hidden1)
my_loss = MyLoss(0.5, 0.5)(y_input, output) # here can also initialize those var1, var2
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, y_input], outputs=my_loss)

model.compile(optimizer= 'adam')
```

Now the model and loss work, as evident by the variables profile, e.g. by keeping the variables after each epoch (their values also make sense if you check the silly loss):

```py
var1_list = []
var2_list = []
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('step %d' % i)
    model.fit([X_train, y_train], None,
              batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)
    var1, var2 = model.layers[-1].get_vars()
    var1_list.append(var1.numpy())
    var2_list.append(var2.numpy())

plt.plot(var1_list, label='var1')
plt.plot(var2_list, 'r', label='var2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I wish to observe/keep the gradient I get a list of (empty?) Tensors:

```py
grads = model.layers[-1].get_gradients()
grads
```

> `ListWrapper([<tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/model/my_loss/mul/Mul:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'gradient_tape/model/my_loss/pow/mul_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>])`

No point in calling `numpy()` over these of course:

```py
grads[0].numpy()
```

> `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

However. Something is obviously right here, since when I use `tf.print(grads)` to print the gradients while training (uncomment the `tf.print(grads)` inside the `call()` function above), the gradients values are printed and they also make sense:

> ```py
> [226.651245, 1]
> [293.38916, 0.998]
> [263.979889, 0.996000171]
> [240.448029, 0.994000435]
> [337.309021, 0.992001]
> [286.644775, 0.990001857]
> [194.823975, 0.988003075]
> [173.756546, 0.98600477]
> [267.330505, 0.984007]
> [139.302826, 0.982009768]
> [310.315216, 0.980013192]
> [263.746216, 0.97801733]
> [267.713, 0.976022303]
> [291.754578, 0.974028111]
> [376.523895, 0.972034812]
> [474.974884, 0.970042467]
> [375.520294, 0.968051136]
> etc. etc.
> ```

Note there is no need to add `g.watch([self.var1, self.var2])`, though adding it doesn't change the issue.

How do I keep track of those gradients (like I keep track of `var1` and `var2`)? What does `tf.print()` "see" that I can't see?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596006/4095235) answer, it seems once you go manual like I did TF might turn off eager execution. The solution is to add `run_eagerly=True` in the `model.compile()` line above:

```py
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam', run_eagerly=True)
```

Then I'm able to call `.numpy()` on my `grads` tensors with no problem, e.g.:

```py
grad1_list = []
grad2_list = []
for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('step %d' % i)
    model.fit([X_train, y_train], None,
              batch_size=32, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, verbose=0)
    grad1, grad2 = model.layers[-1].get_gradients()
    grad1_list.append(grad1.numpy())
    grad2_list.append(grad2.numpy())

plt.plot(grad1_list, label='grad1')
plt.plot(grad2_list, 'r', label='grad2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]